# Trying to find all the lines having a matching string in the file then save the result in a file in a separate directory in Hadoop HDFS

Tags: hadoop, grep, hdfs

I have a file **SimpleInput.txt** inside **SimpleDir** directory in HDFS. I want to output all the lines in this file which contains the words '**texas**'. After that, I need to save the result in a directory **SimpleOutput** which should be inside the **SimpleDir.**

I have created the directory SimpleOutput inside SimpleDir.

I have tried many commands like:

```
hdfs dfs -cat /SimpleDir/SimpleInput.txt | grep -i "texas"
```

With this, I am able to print all the lines having the word 'texas' but can't able to save the result inside SimpleOutput directory.

Other I have tried this command also:

```
hdfs dfs -cat /SimpleDir/SimpleInput.txt | grep -i "texas" /SimpleDir/SimpleOutput
```

It shows this:

```
grep: /SimpleDir/SimpleOutput: No such file or directory
cat: Unable to write to output str
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to redirect the output to the grep to a file

```
hdfs dfs -cat /SimpleDir/SimpleInput.txt | grep -i "texas" > /SimpleDir/SimpleOutput
```

Then you must use `hdfs put` to upload the local file.

Alternatively, the same can be done in Spark using the filter function

Comment: It shows me this thing again                                                                        
   ```bash: /SimpleDir/SimpleOutput: No such file or directory```                                              but I have SimpleOutput directory inside SimpleDir.

Comment: When I run this    ```hdfs dfs -ls /SimpleDir ```. It shows this:                                                       
  ```Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup       4891 2020-01-19 15:23 /SimpleDir/SimpleInput.txt
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera supergroup          0 2020-01-19 15:38 /SimpleDir/SimpleOutput ```

Comment: You cannot send grepped output to HDFS. The command I show is writing to local disk, and unless you're sudo user, you cannot write to the root path

Answer (score 0):

This problem solved with this:

```
hadoop org.apache.hadoop.examples.Grep /SimpleDir/SimpleInput.txt /SimpleDir/SimpleOutput .*texas*.
```